# View arguments in entity selection

Tags: views, entities, users

I have a profile type which uses an autocomplete field which references to another profile. As an entity type i selected user and for filtering the results i use an entity selection with views where i choose what view to filter my content. So far so good , but i've seen that i can pass additional arguments to the view. My question is: How could i pass the input from autocomplete to the referenced view ? ( what should i type in the view arguments field to get the input from autocomplete ? )

Comment: i think its the other way round : the view provides the values for the autocomplete, not that the autocomplete provides a filter to the view ...

Comment: i see . is there any possible solution to my question ? I started to modify the query executed by the view , but i do not know how to grab the value of the autocomplete field...

Comment: what url does the view get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a module which it will alter the query executed by the view and by grabbing the input from url generated by the autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking doesn't quite make sense if I understand it correctly.  You see, the view you're choosing when setting up the field is used *before* your user has even entered anything in the auto-complete field.  So you can't have that be an argument.  The view is generated and used prior to any input.

The view is used simply to determine which set of users are available for the auto-complete field.  It doesn't make sense to generate the view after the user has already entered in a value, because at that point they've already made a selection anyway.

So - I'm wondering, since you're asking about basing that view on user input, if what you're looking for is simply something like the 'auto-complete' functionality which exists with entity and user/node references.  If you select for your field to be Autocomplete, when the user starts typing in a username, a list of related suggestions will automatically appear at the bottom.

[image]

Here's an example of a user reference field with autocomplete turned on

[image]

Comment: Yes . It does but i have installed profile2 module and i would like to search after profile's name. That's the reason why i'm using views in the first place... Do you have a better idea how could i do it ?

Comment: By the way , If i use an entity selection the sort criteria from view is applicable after the user's input !

Comment: And as a reply to your second part of the answer, i need to sort what users may appear in result box of autcomplete field...

Comment: Ah, I see. So you're doing it because of the sort. So I assume your sort isn't just alphabetical - the default with auto-complete? I don't see how you can pass the argument to your view through a URL as you're asking because the user will not have entered anything into the autocomplete field yet when the form is launched! So the URL will not know that input yet. Right? That's why I'm confused. There are ways to pass arguments to your view via php (not always recommended) in which case you can use specific fields, but again, the user input will not be available yet when that is evaluated